Creating an Excel Pivot Table with Weekdays as Columns and Lessons as Rows for people
Question:
I have a dataset (xlsx) where teachers have recorded their availability for lessons throughout the week. Each entry includes the weekday and the lesson period (e.g., Monday Lesson 1 8:00-8:45). If they are note available there is a 1, otherwise the cell is empty. The rows contain the teachers names and the colums contain the weekday and the lesson period (Mo Lesson 1, Tue Lesson 1,..., Fr Lesson 11).
I want to create a Pivot Table in Excel where the columns represent weekdays (Monday to Friday) and the rows represent lesson periods (1st to 11th). Additionally, I want the ability to filter the Pivot Table based on specific teachers.
Could anyone guide me on how to efficiently structure my data and create such a Pivot Table? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
For the Pivot Table itself, I attempted to organize the data with weekdays as columns and lesson periods as rows. I expected that by dragging the appropriate fields into the Pivot Table's rows and columns, I would be able to achieve the desired matrix-like layout but it did not work.

Can you provide a sample file?

Can I upload files here?

Assuming your data looks something like this (4 teachers = 4 rows, 11 lessons * 5 days = 55 columns) where "1" populated cells = unavailable and blank cells = available :

You should transform the data to look like this (long format) :

It's been done here with PowerQuery (unpivot the 55 columns, splitting one of the resulting column into 3 columns ("Day";"Lesson";"Time") and replace blank data with 0).
Then, you can produce a pivot table, like this one :

With "Lessons" in rows field, "Day" in columns field, and "Teachers" in filter field. We also put "Availabality" in the filter area (0 : teacher's available ; 1 : teacher's not available). "Availability" is used to count in the "Values" area of the pivot table.
EDIT : To automate the export in PDF format of one pivot table for each teacher, you could use VBA.
Sub ExportPDFTeachers()
    Dim Feuille As Worksheet
    Dim PTFiltre As PivotTable
    Dim PF As PivotField
    Dim PItem As PivotItem
    Dim NomPDF As String

    ' Name of the sheet containing the pivot table
    Dim NomFeuille As String
    NomFeuille = "pivot_table"
    
    ' Name of the filter field to interact with
    Dim NomEnseignant As String
    NomEnseignant = "Teachers"
    
    ' Set the sheet containing the pivot table
    Set Feuille = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NomFeuille)
    
    ' Set the pivot table
    Set PTFiltre = Feuille.PivotTables(1)
    
    ' Set the filter field inside the pivot table
    Set PF = PTFiltre.PivotFields(NomEnseignant)
    
   ' Clear all filters from the "Teachers" field
    PF.ClearAllFilters
    
    ' Map each element of the "Teachers" field
    For Each PItem In PF.PivotItems
    
        ' Set all elements to false except the current element
        For Each Item In PF.PivotItems
            If Item.Name <> PItem.Name Then
                Item.Visible = False
            End If
        Next Item
        
        ' Select the current item
        PItem.Visible = True
        
        ' Filename of the PDF
        NomPDF = PItem.Name & ".pdf"
        
        ' Export the sheet to PDF
        Feuille.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NomPDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
        ' Clear the filter
        PF.ClearAllFilters
    Next PItem
    
    MsgBox "PDF has been generated"
End Sub

Output :


Thank you. How could I print these as a PDF for each teacher? Is there a straigt forward way? Thank you.

To automate this, you'll need to use VBA integrated with Excel. I've provided a sample of code which should do the trick.

Thank you sincerely for your help. I'll give it a try and see how it goes. Should I encounter any hurdles, may I reach out to you for guidance? I am grateful for your support.

It should be OK. The code works but could be optimized I guess. If If I'm around in the next few days, I'll be able to help. Otherwise submit another question on SO with "PowerQuery","Pivot Table" or "VBA" tag.
